# Implement a deduplication trigger in Oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger

I am new in Oracle DB. We are using Toad for Oracle. I need to implement a deduplication trigger for our table. It's an alarms table and a third party vendor will be sending alarms to our database. Basically, it's a catch-all alarms. Duplicates are those with the same IP, alarm remarks and severity.

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO t_alarms (IP, remarks, severity) VALUES ('10.10.10.10', 'VOICESERVER IS DOWN', '5')
INSERT INTO t_alarms (IP, remarks, severity) VALUES ('10.10.10.10', 'VOICESERVER IS DOWN', '5')
INSERT INTO t_alarms (IP, remarks, severity) VALUES ('10.10.10.19', 'VOICESERVER IS DOWN', '5')
INSERT INTO t_alarms (IP, remarks, severity) VALUES ('10.10.10.19', 'VOICESERVER IS DOWN', '5')
```

And then my table looks like this:

```
IP          REMARKS               SEVERITY TALLY FIRSTOCCUR         LASTOCCUR
10.10.10.10 'VOICESERVER IS DOWN' 5        2     2/21/2014 01:00:03 2/22/2014 02:00:03
10.10.10.19 'VOICESERVER IS DOWN' 5        2     2/21/2014 06:00:03 2/22/2014 06:30:03
```

where:
Tally is the count of how many times my alarms happen
FirstOccur is the date/time when it first inserted/happen
LastOccur is the date/time when it last occur

Is there a way or a script to implement this dedupe process through triggers?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the sort of task that you would want to use triggers on tables for.

If you really wanted to use a trigger, you could declare `t_alarms` as a view, rather than as a table.  You could then write an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view that translated `INSERT` statements on the view into `UPDATE` statements against a new base table.

Were it me, though, I'd let the `INSERT` statements go into a table which allows duplicates and then create a materialized view on top of that table that does the aggregation.  You can have that materialized view refresh `ON COMMIT` if you want to ensure that the data in the materialized view is always in sync with the data in the detail table.

Comment: I see. Trigger is just the first thing that comes to mind. Buy i can also resort to doing your suggestion. I have a question, can a stored proc handle this? Or it will just affect dbase performance?

Comment: @user60216 - If the third party vendor can call stored procedures rather than issuing `INSERT` statements, yes, you could use stored procedures.

Comment: Actually the INSERT statements are being done on our side. So it's possible to do it in store proc like, select the whole table into a temp table distinctly, add a field to count the duplicates, delete the duplicates, then insert the values from temp table to main table this time include the count when inserting values (i hope i explain it well. Lol!)