# Deduplication/normalization of string column on insert

Tags: database-design, normalization, sqlite

I have a database of text tuples. Imagine e.g. full file paths + standard comments. Then you dump large file tree and generate comments for files. A file can have lots of comments, but their text repeats exactly. The DB gets into several GBs size, so I think it's quite big for sqlite standard, I'm a noob here though.

Anyways, since strings in individual columns do repeat quite a lot, but combinations are original, I thought I can have tables for distinct original strings, and combinations just as tuples of foreign keys (I believe that's called normalization), then a `VIEW`, preserving all API, for reading.

**The question is, can I implement deduplication mechanism on the DB side for insert?**

I thought of something like `INSERT` on `(text_column1, text_column2, text_column3)` and then write some kind of `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, that would split it into 3 `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` commands + 1 insert into relation table. But I don't think it is even possible to have different "interface" and "storage" schema. I certainly failed to write it.

I have supplementary questions which tightly related (thus not worthy of separate entries, I believe):

1. Maybe sqlite3 already does string deduplication behind the scenes? (I doubt it, since mutable strings would complicate things a bit. Nothing undoable though.)
2. If it's hard then maybe it's a bad idea for some reason?

If it helps my data is read-only once inserted.

I've read:

1. [Does PostgreSQL have a variable character storage layer that optimizes storage space by automatic dedupe?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/does-postgresql-have-a-variable-character-storage-layer-that-optimizes-storage-s)
2. [Implement a deduplication trigger in Oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/implement-a-deduplication-trigger-in-oracle)
3. [Automatic deduplication (normalization) of strings in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95856/automatic-deduplication-normalization-of-strings-in-mysql)

But they regard different SQL systems, and don't really answer general question. I gather that this is not a popular problem and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough sketch. I could only test with [SQLite 3.8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=3416bb1727f7abe740def4caff7da65b) and it appears as if `UPSERT` is introduced in [2018-06-04 - Release 3.24.0](https://www.sqlite.org/news.html). I.e. the following is untested, but hopefully you can make something out of it anyhow

```
create table Texts
( tid integer not null primary key AUTOINCREMENT
, textval varchar(20) not null unique);

create index x1 on texts (textval);

create table T
( x int not null 
, tid int not null references texts (tid)
, primary key (x, tid) );

create view v as 
   select t.x, texts.textval
   from t
   join texts
       on t.tid = texts.tid
;

CREATE TRIGGER trig1 
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON V 
BEGIN
        -- insert unless textval is already in place
        INSERT INTO texts (textval)
        VALUES (NEW.textval) ON CONFLICT (textval) DO NOTHING;

        -- lookup tid for textval
        insert into t (x, tid)
        select NEW.x, texts.tid
        from texts where texts.textval = NEW.textval;

END;
```

rowid appears to be recommended over [autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), but that is sort of beside the point so I used it anyhow.

For 3.8 I used this ugly workaround:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON V 
BEGIN
        -- insert unless textval is already in place
        INSERT INTO texts (textval)
        SELECT NEW.textval FROM (VALUES(1))
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM texts WHERE textval = NEW.textval 
        );

        --lookup tid for textval
        insert into t (x, tid)
        select NEW.x, texts.tid
        from texts where texts.textval = NEW.textval;
END;
```

You can try it at [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=e1605fa144116d18d959b2ee01adcf58). Test:

```
insert into V (x,textval) values (1,'a'); 
insert into V (x,textval) values (5,'bb');  
insert into V (x,textval) values (15,'a');

select * from v;
x   textval
1   a
5   bb
15  a

select * from texts;
tid textval
1   a
2   bb

select * from t;
x   tid
1   1
5   2
15  1
```

Comment: Your example gave ma a nice kickstart. My toy is more complicated, as it has two string repositories and a N-M relation between strings in them. So the insert trigger is a bit more complicated, as it needs to pull two ids - one for each repo, for final insert. But it was close enough, I am not sure if I should post my example as well. IMHO it's a bit richer. Regarding the workaround, I've also tripped on this, however we don't need `UPSERT` here, fortunately `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` idiom was already present as `INSERT OR IGNORE`. `UPSERT` does supersede it, but there's no need to update.

Comment: You did the right thing postning your own solution, since mine was just a sketch to get you going. For future questions, post ddl and some sample data as in your answer (or a fiddle or similar). You will get much more respons and help if people dont have to guess and create the ddl by them self.

Comment: Yea, but I came up it with after your help. I didn't have any toy DDL before, I just mingled with my "production". I was honestly thinking it's not a popular/good idea, since I couldn't find any similar answer. BTW in my case it worked pretty well, DB size dropped from 2.2.GB to 0.6 and with correct indexes and joins basically maintained speed (5-10% drop for creating DB). Great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of the completeness, it works pretty fine. After kickstarted by Lennart's answer. Here is my final solution.

I have separate unique text repositories and an N-M relation between them:

```
CREATE TABLE "text_group1" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT null PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "text"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE "text_group2" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT null PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "text"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE text1_text2 (
    text1_id integer NOT NULL,
    text2_id integer NOT NULL,
    foreign key (text1_id) references text_group1 (id),
    foreign key (text2_id) references text_group2 (id)
)
```

A view to see original format:

```
CREATE VIEW text1_text2_view AS   
   select text_group1.text AS text1, text_group2.text AS text2
   from text1_text2
   join text_group1
       on text_group1.id = text1_id
   join text_group2
       on text_group2.id = text2_id
```

**The cool part, which is what I call deduplication trigger.** I wasn't aware that it's possible to add a trigger on a view:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON text1_text2_view
BEGIN
        -- insert new texts into unique text groups
        INSERT INTO text_group1 (text)
        VALUES (NEW.text1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

        INSERT INTO text_group2 (text)
        VALUES (NEW.text2) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

        -- pickup ids from unique string repos and insert into normalized relation table
        insert into text1_text2 (text1_id, text2_id)
           select text_group1.id, (SELECT text_group2.id FROM text_group2 WHERE text_group2.text = NEW.text2) id2
             from text_group1
             where text_group1.text = NEW.text1;
END
```

The ugly part is selection statement, because in case of more text repositories the 1st id and it's `FROM WHERE` are separated by sub selections.

We can insert data as into original 2 text-column table via the view:

```
INSERT INTO text1_text2_view (text1, text2) VALUES ("g1_text1", "g2_text1")
INSERT INTO text1_text2_view (text1, text2) VALUES ("g1_text2", "g2_text2")
INSERT INTO text1_text2_view (text1, text2) VALUES ("g1_text1", "g2_text2")
```

The result is two strings in each repository, and a view with 3 tuples.

Comment: Some feedback on your ddl. UNIQUE is not necessary for primary Keys. Default null is the default, you can leave that out. Text1_text2 should probably have a composite primary key